# Why do we care about perfect sets?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

When I first heard the name `perfect' set, I thought that these would be especially nice sets that show up a lot. Maybe it's because I haven't done that much analysis, but it seems like perfect sets are introduced, you can prove a funny theorem about uncountability of them in certain spaces, and then you're done and they never come up again.

Why does anyone care about perfect sets? What's so special about them?

Comment: How do you know they "never come up again"? You have "finished" mathematics? I haven't gotten as far as you, but it's my impression that perfect sets come up a lot more in analysis than perfect numbers do in number theory

Comment: Is your question "why are they called perfect?" or "what are some properties/theorems related to perfect sets?" Those have very different answers.

Comment: I think closer to the second one.

Comment: @bof I don't mean to imply I've finished mathematics, I'm just asking where they do come up again, since I'm not seeing them and think it's strange that I'm not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can show that perfect subsets in separable metric spaces have size continuum (i.e. $|\mathbb{R}|$, also denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\mathfrak{c}$) and that every closed subset of a complete separable metric space (also called a Polish space for short, in honour of the many Polish mathematicians that worked on this theory, a mix of set theory and (metric) topology, called descriptive set theory) is either countable or the union of a countable set and a non-empty perfect set, so has size $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$. That size dichotomy also holds for all Borel sets (the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on a Polish space that contains all open sets) and this also is proved using perfect sets : uncountable Borel sets of Polish contain homeomorphic copies of the Cantor set, a quite ubiquitous perfect space/set. This can in fact be extended to so-called analytic sets too. Very many of the sets mathematicians use in practice, e.g. in proofs etc are Borel sets or analytic sets and so (using perfect sets, indirectly), the continuum hypothesis holds for such sets. This sort of "explains" why that hypothesis seems so plausible to many mathematicians (while being, it turns out, undecidable by the usual set theory axioms).

So perfect sets, especially Cantor sets, are an important idea in some branches of topology/set theory, like descriptive set theory. But one doesn't meet it very often, unless one studies that field in more depth. AFAIK it's not used much in applied branches (like differential equations, or physics). It's nice to know, it has a nice theory and has beautiful properties (the Cantor space is one of my favourites too). "perfect" is more of a homage to that I think. The word perfect is used elsewhere in topology with another meaning (perfectly normal..), so beware. There are also "perfect maps", closely related to compactness.

Comment: Perfect sets can also be considered as the boundary between closed sets (the set of limit points of the set is a subset of the set) and dense in themselves sets (the set is a subset of the set of limit points of the set). Perhaps one way to very roughly put it --- closed sets that are not dense in themselves have too many points and dense in themselves sets that are not closed don't have enough points. Perfect sets are those sets that are both closed and dense in themselves.

Comment: By moderately long but elementary methods we have (1) A non-empty completely metrizable space $Y$ with no isolated points has a sub-space homeomorphic to the Cantor set (so $|Y|\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$  ).... and (2) If $X$ is completely metrizable and $Y\subset X$ then $Y$ is completely metrizable  iff $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X$.... Therefore (with $X=\Bbb R$ and $Y=\Bbb Q$ ), we see that $\Bbb Q$ is not $G_{\delta}$ in $\Bbb R$   (which someone on this site wanted to see a proof of, without using the Baire Category Theorem).